# Output of a LTI system

Tags: convolution, linear-systems

I'm trying to resolve this exercise but I don't even know where to start.
Do I have to apply convolution?

**It appears that this question is classified as *homework* - this an exame problem which I was/am studying  **, not homework *per se*

The "simple" doubt was I had no idea where to start -The answer by Fat32 helped me a lot: "express the input x1[n] in terms of shifted and scaled copies of x0[n]"

I can upload the resolution with the graphics if this help the question.

Thank you,
Eddy

[image]

Comment: No, you must apply fundamental LTI property: Express the input $x_1[n]$ in terms of **shifted and scaled** copies of $x_0[n]$, and then the output will be obtained in terms of the same shifted and scaled copies of the response, $y_0[n]$ ,  of the system to the basic input $x_0[n]$...

Comment: Eddy, this is not a place to post your homework.

Comment: I simply don't know how to do this question, but thank you for your help.
If you wish I will gladly send my homework

Comment: @Eddygrinder: Why don't you try to follow Fat32's advice?

Comment: @MattL. sure I will

Answer (score 2):

@FAT32 thank you so much for your help.

$x_1[n] = 2x_0[n-4] + x_0[n-2] + x_0[n-6]$

Thus the output is:

$-\delta[n]-2\delta[n-1]-2\delta[n-2]-2\delta[n-3]+2\delta[n-5]+2\delta[n-6]+2\delta[n-7]+\delta[n-8]$

Comment: Good work! You can accept your own answer if you like.